# Has_many through association - View? Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and I'm building an application where a user profile can apply for jobs. I created a has_many through association. But I don't find a way to define my controllers and views. Here's my code:

Models:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :profileimg, :default_url => ":style/profile-img.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :profileimg, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :relationships
  has_many :jobs, through: :relationships
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employer

  has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :profiles, through: :relationships


end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :job
end
```

PS: I can create relationships on the Rails Console and it works.

How should I write my RelationshipsController? and how do I put a button on my Job page where the current_user.profile can apply for that job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should show something like this:

```
Job            Apply For This Job
```

Create a member route in `Job` like this:

```
resources :jobs do
  member do
    post 'apply_for_job'
  end
end
```

When someone clicks on the `Apply For This Job` button send a AJAX request to the above route. And before this all I think there should be a relation between `Profile` and `User` like `User has_one Profile` and `Profile belongs_to User`. So in the `jobs_controller` create a action:

```
def apply_for_job
  @job = Job.find params[:id] #This should be in a before_filter
  @profile = current_user.profile
  @profile.relationships.create(job: @job)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And then in the `views` create a view in `jobs` folder `apply_for_job.js.erb` and respond accordingly like for example by making the `Apply For This Job` to `Successfully Applied`. I have not handled any error above so you can do it as you require but this should get you a basic idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah, the profile and user have the relationship you suggested, I just didn't write them in the question. I'll try this and let you know :)

Comment: When adding the route to my routes I got the error " wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) "

Comment: Oh sorry it was my syntax error, I have edited the answer.

Comment: You also need to associate a profile with that job so how do you think that will happen? And what would happen if you just visit the url and do nothing in the back end?

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I created the .js file with just an alert to see if it was working. When I click on the apply button, the alert works, but the relationship is not created. So I guess I'll have tp change something at the apply_for_job method. My relationships table receives the job_id and profile_id.. in the apply_for_job method, it says: "@profile.relationships.create(job_id: @job) " 
Then I changed it to @profile.relationships.create(job_id: @job.id), but it didn't work

Comment: Yay!!! it is finally working, my mistake was that I forgot to add the method to the before_filter. haha Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are just files in `app/controllers`. Just add `jobs_controller.rb` there, either by hand or with `rails g controller Jobs` on the CLI.

The views go into `app/views/jobs/`. It's probably best to run a `rails g scaffold Example` to get a full set of model, controller & views as an example or work through a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the structure. However, I don't know how to develop the Create method for the Relationship..